# Работа со временем

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица в которой есть два параметра типа *date*.
Есть функция DATEDIFF, которая возвращает разницу между двумя временными точками, к примеру, в часах.
Как можно узнать, сколько прошло времени с момента начала операции *date1* до момента конца *date2*, исключая время на синхронизацию, которое происходит каждый день с 12-00 до 13-00.
Пример:

```
date1           | date2
----------------------------------    
2020-01-14 12:00| 2020-01-14 16:00
2020-01-14 14:00| 2020-01-14 15:00
```

На входе получить, временную разницу - минус время в промежутке от 12:00 до 13:00:

```
date3           
-----  
3
1
```

Как это можно сделать? И можно ли вообще?

Comment: Несколько раз перечитал, но так и не понял, что нужно получить и из чего.

Comment: Мне нужно получить сколько прошло времени с начала операции date1 по ее окончания date2 исключая время синхронизации, так как оно фиксировано каждый день в одно  то же время

Comment: И в чем проблема? Посчитать разницу? Вычесть из неё час? Узнать, нужно ли вычитать час? Это все элементарные подзадачи, вы не можете собрать их в одну функцию?

Comment: @Эникейщик в перекрытии интервалов, очевидно?

Comment: В этом и суть, я не понимаю, как сделать проверку, что нужно ли вычитать время или нет.

Comment: так и напишите, case, проверьте, если date2 меньше 13, или date1 меньше 12, то просто дифф. Если date1 > 12 и date2< 13 то 0, иначе интервалы перекрываются, надо сколько-то вычитать. Тут вопрос у вас временные метки строго в 00 минут, или нет.

Comment: Считаете продолжительность. Считаете пересечение заданного интервала с интервалом обслуживания и продолжительность этого пересечения. Вычитаете. Профит.

Comment: Ну вручную вы же как то посчитали :)  Переложите этот же алгоритм в код.

Comment: *У меня есть таблица в которой есть два параметра типа date.* У них компонент даты всегда равный?

Comment: @teran Если делать через CASE, не будет ли он "ругаться" на формат записи с годом или придется перед этим вытаскивать строго время?

Comment: @Akina Если я правильно тебя понял, то да. Если нет, вот формат записи времени скопированный из базы |2020-10-04 10:02:28.000|

Comment: @Akina А если у него данный запрос выполняется несколько суток и начинается к примеру в 12:58, а заканчивается в 12:02?

Comment: @Blackmeser не то, что суток, он может и пол года выполняться)

Comment: Ну если оба поля содержат значение для одного и того же дня, то тогда алгоритм я вроде описАл... Альтернативно можно считать два куска отдельно (до 12 и после 13) и складывать. Если же процесс растянут на несколько дней, то режь его на три части - первый день, последний день, остальное, для первого и последнего считай по описанному алгоритму, а для средних добавляй тупо по 23 часа на день.

Comment: @Cycl1k в один простой запрос всё это не уместить. Для каждой записи: Для промежуточных дней (>=3) можно брать тупо 23 часа * число таких дней, для первого дня извлекаем время и: if (date1.time <= 12:00) {first = 12:00-date1.time + 11:00 "остаток дня"} else if (12:00 < date1.time <= 13:00) {first = 11:00} else {first = 24:00 -date1.time }, для последнего дня if (date1.time <= 12:00) {second = date2.time} else if (12:00 < date2.time <= 13:00) {second = 12:00} else {second = date2.time - 1:00}, после чего просто суммируете в часах (или минутах...): число промежуточных дней * 23 + first + second.